# AreYouHuman and django

Tags: django, captcha

I am trying to get http://areyouahuman.com/ capcha working on my site
I found
https://gist.github.com/klanestro/9572114

I subclassed it

```
class Turtle_Form(forms.ModelForm,AreYouHumanForm):
    ''' This is code to make sure the User automatically saves the
    user to the database in context.
    '''
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit']=False
        obj = super(Turtle_Form, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request:
            obj.user = self.request.user
            obj.save()
        return obj #<--- Return saved object to caller.

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        return super(Turtle_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and

```
class OfertoCreateForm(Turtle_Form):


class Meta:
    model = Oferto
    fields = (  "name",
                "description",
                "tags",
                "time",
                "requirements",
                "location",
                "image",
                'AreYouHumanForm',

        )
```

but nothing comes up on the form, no errors nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field in that gist is called `session_secret`, which is the name you should be using in the `fields` tuple.